# Could Evil containment wave defeat Jiren?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

We already saw

> Vegita break out of the bottle when he was sealed with Mafuba.

So it is not a definite technique to get rid of powerful foe.
My question is that, can Jiren be sealed even for a moment so they can toss him out of the field? Or is he simply too powerful to be effected by Mafuba?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isnt any official data to say yes or no. There are arguments to sustain it could or it couldnt. For example,

Why it could: as you mentioned Vegeta was sealed in the jar and if it wasnt for Roshi's small kamehamehameha wave, he wouldnt have been freed.

Why it couldnt: Hit tried to inmobilize Jiren with a technique of his own which is a "time cage" and Jiren broke it. It would seem in Dragon Ball any trapping technique can be broken with enough power, other example is Kale breaking the Cocotte zone that traps the victim in another dimension, and as far as we know Jiren's power seems to be much greater than Vegeta by now.

Answer (score 2):

Master Roshi freed Vegeta from the container by direction his "missed" attack towards the container. Vegeta was in his super saiyan blue form, but was able to get free **after** master roshi broke the seal from outside. Meaning it is strong enough to at least hold a super saiyan god captive.

We also know that Zamasu was **only** able to break free because Goku forgot the seals for the container. Zamasu was strong enough to kill all the gods. This basically means that someone stronger than the gods can be sealed as well when sealed properly.

So to sum it up, yes Jiren can be sealed. Mafuba has no limits as it forces an entity into the container. The only way to get out of it is by breaking the seal.

[Click here for more info about the Mafuba.](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Evil_Containment_Wave)

Answer (score 1):

I see there have been pretty good answers for the same however, I would like to differ and say No. 
This would be my explanation for the same.

Jiren is at the level of a God of destruction. His power could possibly even surpass a few Gods of destructions(Like Vermouth, Beerus etc).

The two times we've seen Jiren fight as of now is against Goku and Hit where he didn't even go all out and didn't even show any signs of tiredness or him being exhausted after these 2 fights.

Firstly, we need to note that the mafuba way can be deflected and since you're referring to dragon ball super, I'm gonna refer to Frost who easily deflects Roshi's mafuba the second time.

It was noted by Vados that Jiren is a fighter who never lets his guard down. This is seen when he dodges UI Goku's kick which Toppo and someone as fast as Dyspo didn't even see coming. Also when hit attacked him once he knocked out goku, we see Jiren immediately react and block it. Jiren's reaction time is near to perfect.

Jiren was able to fight UI Goku when every part of Goku's body was acting on his own. Even at the same time, Jiren wasn't even fighting at full strength and seemed pretty heavily suppressed.

Even during Hit, unlike goku who took a while to adapt to time skip. Jiren didn't take a single hit from time skip even from the start he was able to keep his guard and block and strike Hit. Once he adapted, he was perfect. Even when Hit created a shadow clone and tried to attack Jiren, we see Jiren immediately react and block it. Even when Hit used an attack which binds Jiren in a cage of time which completely inhibits movement, we see him effortlessly break out of it and block hit's attack with just his eyes.

He effortlessly controlled and pushed back a spirit bomb from SSJB + Kaioken *20 goku with just his eyes.

We also see Jiren effortlessly block hit's invisible shockwave, which is known for killing fighters with a single hit.

Every attack has its limitations and I strongly believe the mafuba wouldn't be effective against someone as strong as a god of destruction. As of now we know the mafuba is strong enough to contain SSJB Vegeta. However, Jiren's power is way beyond Vegeta's. Based on his display of power in his fights with Goku and Hit , I believe it can be concluded with certainty that this technique wouldn't work against someone like Jiren.

One of 3 possibilities might happen:

1. The wave might not be strong enough to contain Jiren's power
2. Jiren might deflect the wave
3. Jiren would end up dodging it